# Packaging a python project

Tags: python-packaging

I created a Myproject folder. Inside this folder, a MyPackage folder is created, in which the files P1.py to P4.py and the **init**.py file are inside, and the rest of the files are setup.py, requirements.txt outside the Mypackage folder. The packages were impoert in **init**.py and imported in each file as follows: @Omidhosseiiini

from MyPackage import 'module'

But it gives this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyPackage'

**init**.py:
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from mysql.connector import connect,Error
import tkinter

P1.Py:
from MyPackage import MongoClient
pass

Packaging a python files